# TikZpicture as newcommand with more than 10 parameters

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, macros, parameters

I would like to build several Pareto diagram figures using a `\newcommand`, like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{xfp}
\definecolor{Azul}{rgb}{0.16, 0.32, 0.75}

\newcommand{\GraficoPareto}[9]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (10,5);
\foreach \i/\j in {0/#6,2/#7,4/#8,6/#9,8/,10/}{
\draw (\i,2pt) -- (\i,-2pt) node[below] { \j };
}
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,5}{
\ifnum\i>0
\draw[densely dashed,gray] (-.1,\i) -- (10.1,\i) node[right] {\textcolor{black}{$\fpeval{20*\i}\%$}};
\else 
\node[right,gray] (Texto) at (10.1,\i) {\textcolor{black}{$\fpeval{20*\i}\%$}};
\fi
\node[left] (Te) at (-0.1,\i) {$\fpeval{8*\i}$};
}
\fill[Azul!100!black,opacity=0.8] (0.02,0) rectangle ({2-0.02},{#1*5/40});
\fill[Azul!100!black,opacity=0.8] (2.02,0) rectangle ({4-0.02},{#2*5/40});
\fill[Azul!100!black,opacity=0.8] (4.02,0) rectangle ({6-0.02},{#3*5/40});
\fill[Azul!100!black,opacity=0.8] (6.02,0) rectangle ({8-0.02},{#4*5/40});
\fill[Azul!100!black,opacity=0.8] (8.02,0) rectangle ({10-0.02},{#5*5/40});
\draw[line width=3pt,orange] (1,{5*(#1/50)}) -- (3,{5*((#1+#2)/50)}) -- (5,{5*((#1+#2+#3)/50)}) -- (7,{5*((#1+#2+#3+#4)/50)}) -- (9,{5*((#1+#2+#3+#4+#5)/50)});
\node (Legendax) at (5,-1) {Soma das horas};
\node (Legenday) at (-1,2.5) {\rotatebox{90}{Frequência}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}

\GraficoPareto{30}{10}{5}{3}{2}{94}{194}{294}{394}


\end{document}
```

Whose result is this:

[image]

However, I would like to insert more two parameters (then 11), where I can to define the final x-labels. But this does not work.

How can I define this figure using 11 parameters?

Comment: Simple answer is don’t. Pass a single argument with tikz key value pairs instead.

Comment: tex syntax only allows `#1` to `#9` but theuser interface even with 9 is very hard to use and hard to read use eithr a key val list as Alan suggests or ifthe values really are a list and you wantto treat them all the same, use a comma list in a single argument

Comment: Could you like to give and example?

Comment: Olá, @AngeloAlianoFilho. You may check some options in [More than 9 argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-to-define-a-command-that-takes-more-than-9-arguments). You may also check [xparse](https://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) and other methods do deal with multiple inputs. On the other hand, I would consider some way to insert your data as a list of numbers as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599133/pareto-diagram-in-latex). Therefore 1 input has all needed data. I'd also think about creating a style file to keep the model save apart the main file.

Comment: By using multiple argument grabbing steps you can grab an arbitrary amount of tokens, but as others already said, why bother, either use a key=value syntax, or use a single argument which is a list.

Comment: Agreed with @Skillmon. Since each data point is simply a number, I would pass a comma separated list and parse with `listofitems` https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems?lang=en or process with Lua

Comment: If you absolutely want this and if "x-labels" means the phrases "Soma das horas" and "Frequência", then instead of having `\GraficoPareto` carry out `\node (Legendax) at (5,-1) {Soma das horas}; \node (Legenday) at (-1,2.5) {\rotatebox{90}{Frequência}}; \end{tikzpicture}` have `\GraficoPareto` call another macro which takes two arguments and does `\node (Legendax) at (5,-1) {#1}; \node (Legenday) at (-1,2.5) {\rotatebox{90}{#2}}; \end{tikzpicture}` and call the unextendible argument-monster as `\GraficoPareto{30}{10}{5}{3}{2}{94}{194}{294}{394}{Soma das horas}{Frequência}`.

Answer (score 6):

I suggested a list based approach. This answer is part of it. The idea is to use one single input of the `newcommand` syntax as broad as possible. Your original idea **is not extendable** (you cannot add more and more inputs as you need), this is a major flaw since *I may guess* you want to extend (expand) for more and more data.

This answer is based on:

1. [Pareto diagram in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/599133/pareto-diagram-in-latex)
2. [Draw Pareto chart with pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30290/draw-pareto-chart-with-pgfplots)
3. https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots
4. [pgfplots: two axis for one dataset e.g. °C and °F](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123317/pgfplots-two-axis-for-one-dataset-e-g-c-and-f)
5. [Distance between bars with pgfplot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/415420/distance-between-bars-with-pgfplot)

I created a `newcommand` with two inputs as the coordinates for the command
`addplot` formated by `axis`.

I suggest you to learn about `pgfplots`, it is an amazing tool. I'm not an expert, there might be better methods to achieve the results you want.

Please note, my answer doesn't compute the frequencies (*Frequência*) instead I just present the cumulated sum (*Acumulado*) manually inserted in the second input argument. There are however a few options:

- Use any math tool or computer code to write down both lists for you;
- Learn how to do the math directly in TikZ (Sorry, I don't know this trick for coordinates);
- Check references from links 4 and 5 to learn how to create tables with your data or external files.

The MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand{\myPareto}[2]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        ylabel={Acumulado},
        xlabel={Soma das horas},
        ymin=0,
        xtick=data,
        axis y line*=left,
        ymajorgrids,
        major y grid style={dashed, thick}
      ]
      \addplot[ybar interval, fill=blue, opacity=0.5] coordinates {#1};
      \addplot[draw, mark=*, orange, ultra thick] coordinates {#2};   
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
      axis y line*=right,
      axis x line=none,
      yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{100*\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=0]\pgfmathresult\%},
      ymin=0,
      ]  
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\myPareto{(94,30) (194,10) (294,5) (394,3) (494,2) (594,0)}
  {(144,30) (244,40) (344,45) (444,48) (544,50)}
\end{document}
```

I added `mark=*` to show the coordinates of second input. The result is presented below.

[image]

Comment: By "expandable", do you mean "extendable"?  As in, able to easily add more points?  Just that "expandable" has a very particular meaning in TeX so should probably be only used to mean TeX's interpretation.

Comment: Oh, I see. Totally misuse of terms of myself. I corrected the terminology. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't construct such (monster of) `\newcommand`. Rather use a table, where are collected data for diagrams. Such approach, according to my opinion, is more clear and flexible (you can simply extend the table with more rows and columns). Beside this, such MWE is better understandable to others, which will be eventually  interested for your code (for example, if you will use it articles for journals):

```
\documentclass[margin=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\pgfplotstableread{
X1      y1      X2      y2
94      30      144     30
194     10      244     40
294     5       344     45
394     3       444     48
494     2       544     50
594     0       nan     nan
}{\datatable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymajorgrids,
    major y grid style={dashed},
    ylabel={Acumulado},
    xtick=data,
    xlabel={Soma das horas},
    ymin=0,
            ]
\addplot [ybar interval, fill=blue, semitransparent]
            table [x=X1, y=y1]   {\datatable};
\addplot [orange, very thick, mark=*]
            table [x=X2, y=y2]   {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line=none,
    yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{int(round(100*\tick))}%
                \pgfmathresult\%
                },
      ymin=0,
      ]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]